# Google cloud its have unlimited storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

its possible for check left space / size storage on gcs ? im forget how much storage size im using after create bucket

Im using gsutil du but they just showing how much im using the space storage

[my total storage using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbCoA.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Google Cloud Storage is almost infinite. When you create a bucket, you do not specify a size like a file system. With the CLI or GUI, you can view how much space you are using, but there is no field to view free space as that is not defined.

Comment: Tell how money do you have, I will tell you how much storage you can get!! :) The GCS space left is virtually infinite. No worry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage operates at exabyte scale with no declared upper limit.  You are highly unlikely to exceed this scale unless you are storing thousands of terabytes per person on the planet earth.

Read:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/how-does-your-cloud-storage-grow-with-a-scalable-plan-and-a-price-drop
- https://siliconangle.com/2021/04/19/google-shares-technical-overview-exabyte-scale-colossus-file-system/
- https://medium.com/swlh/how-well-does-your-database-scale-a3827951757e

If you are operating at this scale, the biggest problem you will have is your GCP bill, not your storage limit.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud Storage can scale to exabytes capacity  with a maximum size limit of 5 TB for individual objects stored in Cloud Storage. So its very rare someone will exhaust that capacity. ​

One should  only keep in mind how much data and on which storage class he or she is  storing in the cloud storage as it’s a cost to him or her.
Please refer the following links :​

​Ref :

1. https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas
2. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/introduction ​
3. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).